# Convert sparse matrix (dgCMatrix) to realRatingMatrix

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning, sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine

I've converted a data frame to a sparse matrix to avoid memory issues and save space, once the original data doesn't fit in the memory.

Now, I need to convert this sparse matrix to a realratingmatrix so I can build a recommender with recommenderlab, but i got the following error:

```
Error in as(aux_max, "realRatingMatrix") : 
  no method or default for coercing “dgCMatrix” to “realRatingMatrix”
```

My sample code is the following:

```
library(Matrix)
UserID<-c(10090,10090,10090,10316,10316)
MovieID <-c(63155,63530,63544,63155,63545)
Rating <-c(2,2,1,2,1)
trainingData<-data.frame(UserIDa,MovieID,Rating)

UIMatrix <- sparseMatrix(i = as.integer(as.factor(trainingData$UserID)),
                         j = as.integer(as.factor(trainingData$MovieID)),
                         x = trainingData$Rating
                        )

dimnames(UIMatrix) <- list(sort(unique(trainingData$UserID)),
                           sort(unique(trainingData$MovieID)))

rrm <- as(UIMatrix, "realRatingMatrix")
```

Can anyone give some advise on how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think I got the answer. 
I coerced the  "dgCMatrix" to "matrix" and then to "realratingmatrix".
Seems to work fine.

```
rrm<- as(  as(UIMatrix, "matrix")   , "realRatingMatrix")
```

Comment: This solutions isn't comletly correct. In fact this method, coerces dgCMatrix to matrix and then to relratingmatrix, but fills the empty cells with "0" which is incorrect.

Comment: Te solution is : datamat_2<-new("realRatingMatrix", data = datamat) . There is a link:http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/recommenderlab/docs/colSds

Answer (score 1):

I just received this error (no method or default for coercing “matrix” to “realRatingMatrix”), I needed to install library(recommenderlab) package.

[error message and solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbY3r.png)

Comment: Please dont post screenshots - just post the text in your answer